# UUID Multiple Times in /dev

Tags: mount, hard-disk, lsblk

I have an external hard drive that shows up many times in /dev whenever its connected. Is there any way I can fix this? Or is it a problem with the drive itself?

[image]

Output of `cat /proc/partitions`:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0     211992 loop0
   7        2     101340 loop2
   7        3      56780 loop3
   7        4      63204 loop4
   7        5     128704 loop5
   7        6     155940 loop6
   7        7     275188 loop7
 259        0  117220824 nvme1n1
 259        1     512000 nvme1n1p1
 259        2  116175993 nvme1n1p2
 259        3     528384 nvme1n1p3
 259        4  488386584 nvme0n1
   8        0 1953514584 sda
   8        1  719323136 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        3  329252864 sda3
   8        5  904936523 sda5
  11        0   45255040 sr0
   8       16  468851544 sdb
   8       32  468851544 sdc
   9        0  937438848 md0
   7        8     165288 loop8
   7        9     166776 loop9
   7       10     249768 loop10
   7       11      66324 loop11
   7       12     224248 loop12
   7       13     223124 loop13
   7       14      66660 loop14
   7       15     331272 loop15
   7       16     266968 loop16
   7       17      52248 loop17
   7       18      52268 loop18
   7       19      32856 loop19
   7       20     156404 loop20
   7       22     112720 loop22
   7       23     183876 loop23
   7       24       3112 loop24
   7       25      32872 loop25
   7       26     183760 loop26
   7       27      56752 loop27
   7       28      63212 loop28
   7       29       1688 loop29
   7       30     211992 loop30
   7       31     283296 loop31
   7       32       3112 loop32
   7       33     101556 loop33
   8      128  488386584 sdi
   8      129  488385536 sdi1
   8       48 7814026583 sdd
   8       49 7814025216 sdd1
   8      192 7814026583 sdm
   8      193 7814025216 sdm1
   8      224 7814026583 sdo
   8      225 7814025216 sdo1
  65       80 7814026583 sdv
  65       81 7814025216 sdv1
   8      144 7814026583 sdj
   8      145 7814025216 sdj1
  66       80 7814026583 sdal
  66       81 7814025216 sdal1
  65      128 7814026583 sdy
  65      129 7814025216 sdy1
  65      208 7814026583 sdad
  65      209 7814025216 sdad1
  65       96 7814026583 sdw
  65       97 7814025216 sdw1
  66       16 7814026583 sdah
  66       17 7814025216 sdah1
  66      144 7814026583 sdap
  66      145 7814025216 sdap1
  65      112 7814026583 sdx
  65      113 7814025216 sdx1
  66      112 7814026583 sdan
  66      113 7814025216 sdan1
  65      240 7814026583 sdaf
  65      241 7814025216 sdaf1
  66      176 7814026583 sdar
  66      177 7814025216 sdar1
  65       16 7814026583 sdr
  65       17 7814025216 sdr1
  65      176 7814026583 sdab
  65      177 7814025216 sdab1
  66        0 7814026583 sdag
  66        1 7814025216 sdag1
  66       32 7814026583 sdai
  66       33 7814025216 sdai1
 130      160 7814026583 sdfo
 130      161 7814025216 sdfo1
  71       48 7814026583 sddl
  71       49 7814025216 sddl1
   8      176 7814026583 sdl
   8      177 7814025216 sdl1
 128      128 7814026583 sdeg
 128      129 7814025216 sdeg1
  65       64 7814026583 sdu
  65       65 7814025216 sdu1
  67      192 7814026583 sdbi
  67      193 7814025216 sdbi1
  70       80 7814026583 sdcx
  70       81 7814025216 sdcx1
  67      144 7814026583 sdbf
  67      145 7814025216 sdbf1
  68       96 7814026583 sdbs
  68       97 7814025216 sdbs1
 129       16 7814026583 sdep
 129       17 7814025216 sdep1
  69       64 7814026583 sdcg
  69       65 7814025216 sdcg1
 130      224 7814026583 sdfs
 130      225 7814025216 sdfs1
  71       32 7814026583 sddk
  71       33 7814025216 sddk1
  71      160 7814026583 sdds
  71      161 7814025216 sdds1
 128       64 7814026583 sdec
 128       65 7814025216 sdec1
  66      128 7814026583 sdao
  66      129 7814025216 sdao1
  71      240 7814026583 sddx
  71      241 7814025216 sddx1
  71      208 7814026583 sddv
  71      209 7814025216 sddv1
  66      208 7814026583 sdat
  66      209 7814025216 sdat1
  67       32 7814026583 sday
  67       33 7814025216 sday1
  71       64 7814026583 sddm
  71       65 7814025216 sddm1
  69      208 7814026583 sdcp
  69      209 7814025216 sdcp1
 129      240 7814026583 sdfd
 129      241 7814025216 sdfd1
 128      112 7814026583 sdef
 128      113 7814025216 sdef1
 132      240 7814026583 sdgz
 132      241 7814025216 sdgz1
  66       96 7814026583 sdam
  66       97 7814025216 sdam1
 133       80 7814026583 sdhf
 133       81 7814025216 sdhf1
  70      240 7814026583 sddh
  70      241 7814025216 sddh1
  68      112 7814026583 sdbt
  68      113 7814025216 sdbt1
  67       96 7814026583 sdbc
  67       97 7814025216 sdbc1
 128       32 7814026583 sdea
 128       33 7814025216 sdea1
 133        0 7814026583 sdha
 133        1 7814025216 sdha1
 133       96 7814026583 sdhg
 133       97 7814025216 sdhg1
 128      224 7814026583 sdem
 128      225 7814025216 sdem1
 133      176 7814026583 sdhl
 133      177 7814025216 sdhl1
  68      208 7814026583 sdbz
  68      209 7814025216 sdbz1
  71       16 7814026583 sddj
  71       17 7814025216 sddj1
  68      240 7814026583 sdcb
  68      241 7814025216 sdcb1
 132      192 7814026583 sdgw
 132      193 7814025216 sdgw1
 133      160 7814026583 sdhk
 133      161 7814025216 sdhk1
 131      240 7814026583 sdgj
 131      241 7814025216 sdgj1
 134      224 7814026583 sdie
 134      225 7814025216 sdie1
 128      192 7814026583 sdek
 128      193 7814025216 sdek1
 132        0 7814026583 sdgk
 132        1 7814025216 sdgk1
   8      368 7814026583 sdjd
   8      369 7814025216 sdjd1
 129       96 7814026583 sdeu
 129       97 7814025216 sdeu1
 135      144 7814026583 sdip
 135      145 7814025216 sdip1
  70      192 7814026583 sdde
  70      193 7814025216 sdde1
  69      144 7814026583 sdcl
  69      145 7814025216 sdcl1
  70       96 7814026583 sdcy
  70       97 7814025216 sdcy1
 128      144 7814026583 sdeh
 128      145 7814025216 sdeh1
 134      144 7814026583 sdhz
 134      145 7814025216 sdhz1
 133      240 7814026583 sdhp
 133      241 7814025216 sdhp1
  69        0 7814026583 sdcc
  69        1 7814025216 sdcc1
  65       48 7814026583 sdt
  65       49 7814025216 sdt1
 132       96 7814026583 sdgq
 132       97 7814025216 sdgq1
 129       64 7814026583 sdes
 129       65 7814025216 sdes1
  71      224 7814026583 sddw
  71      225 7814025216 sddw1
 135      160 7814026583 sdiq
 135      161 7814025216 sdiq1
 128      176 7814026583 sdej
 128      177 7814025216 sdej1
   8      272 7814026583 sdix
   8      273 7814025216 sdix1
  65       32 7814026583 sds
  65       33 7814025216 sds1
  65        0 7814026583 sdq
  65        1 7814025216 sdq1
  67      128 7814026583 sdbe
  67      129 7814025216 sdbe1
 130       80 7814026583 sdfj
 130       81 7814025216 sdfj1
  67        0 7814026583 sdaw
  67        1 7814025216 sdaw1
 129        0 7814026583 sdeo
 129        1 7814025216 sdeo1
   8      288 7814026583 sdiy
   8      289 7814025216 sdiy1
  71      144 7814026583 sddr
  71      145 7814025216 sddr1
 134       16 7814026583 sdhr
 134       17 7814025216 sdhr1
 130      144 7814026583 sdfn
 130      145 7814025216 sdfn1
 128       16 7814026583 sddz
 128       17 7814025216 sddz1
 129      176 7814026583 sdez
 129      177 7814025216 sdez1
 135        0 7814026583 sdig
 135        1 7814025216 sdig1
  66      192 7814026583 sdas
  66      193 7814025216 sdas1
  67      176 7814026583 sdbh
  67      177 7814025216 sdbh1
  68      192 7814026583 sdby
  68      193 7814025216 sdby1
 134      160 7814026583 sdia
 134      161 7814025216 sdia1
 132      128 7814026583 sdgs
 132      129 7814025216 sdgs1
   8      208 7814026583 sdn
   8      209 7814025216 sdn1
 134       48 7814026583 sdht
 134       49 7814025216 sdht1
   8      304 7814026583 sdiz
   8      305 7814025216 sdiz1
 130      192 7814026583 sdfq
 130      193 7814025216 sdfq1
 135      176 7814026583 sdir
 135      177 7814025216 sdir1
 135      192 7814026583 sdis
 135      193 7814025216 sdis1
  67      224 7814026583 sdbk
  67      225 7814025216 sdbk1
  66      224 7814026583 sdau
  66      225 7814025216 sdau1
  69      240 7814026583 sdcr
  69      241 7814025216 sdcr1
  69       48 7814026583 sdcf
  69       49 7814025216 sdcf1
  68       80 7814026583 sdbr
  68       81 7814025216 sdbr1
  71       80 7814026583 sddn
  71       81 7814025216 sddn1
 132      160 7814026583 sdgu
 132      161 7814025216 sdgu1
 131       48 7814026583 sdfx
 131       49 7814025216 sdfx1
  68      176 7814026583 sdbx
  68      177 7814025216 sdbx1
  66       48 7814026583 sdaj
  66       49 7814025216 sdaj1
 135       80 7814026583 sdil
 135       81 7814025216 sdil1
  70      224 7814026583 sddg
  70      225 7814025216 sddg1
 131      128 7814026583 sdgc
 131      129 7814025216 sdgc1
 133      128 7814026583 sdhi
 133      129 7814025216 sdhi1
  69      112 7814026583 sdcj
  69      113 7814025216 sdcj1
 131      208 7814026583 sdgh
 131      209 7814025216 sdgh1
  67       80 7814026583 sdbb
  67       81 7814025216 sdbb1
  71      176 7814026583 sddt
  71      177 7814025216 sddt1
  70       32 7814026583 sdcu
  70       33 7814025216 sdcu1
 128       48 7814026583 sdeb
 128       49 7814025216 sdeb1
  66       64 7814026583 sdak
  66       65 7814025216 sdak1
 129      224 7814026583 sdfc
 129      225 7814025216 sdfc1
 135      128 7814026583 sdio
 135      129 7814025216 sdio1
 134      192 7814026583 sdic
 134      193 7814025216 sdic1
 132       16 7814026583 sdgl
 132       17 7814025216 sdgl1
  69       80 7814026583 sdch
  69       81 7814025216 sdch1
  65      160 7814026583 sdaa
  65      161 7814025216 sdaa1
  71      128 7814026583 sddq
  71      129 7814025216 sddq1
 132       48 7814026583 sdgn
 132       49 7814025216 sdgn1
 129      160 7814026583 sdey
 129      161 7814025216 sdey1
  68       32 7814026583 sdbo
  68       33 7814025216 sdbo1
 130      176 7814026583 sdfp
 130      177 7814025216 sdfp1
 132       80 7814026583 sdgp
 132       81 7814025216 sdgp1
 132      208 7814026583 sdgx
 132      209 7814025216 sdgx1
 135       16 7814026583 sdih
 135       17 7814025216 sdih1
  68      160 7814026583 sdbw
  68      161 7814025216 sdbw1
  67      240 7814026583 sdbl
  67      241 7814025216 sdbl1
  70       64 7814026583 sdcw
  70       65 7814025216 sdcw1
  71      192 7814026583 sddu
  71      193 7814025216 sddu1
 129      144 7814026583 sdex
 129      145 7814025216 sdex1
 135      112 7814026583 sdin
 135      113 7814025216 sdin1
 134       80 7814026583 sdhv
 134       81 7814025216 sdhv1
   8      320 7814026583 sdja
   8      321 7814025216 sdja1
  69      160 7814026583 sdcm
  69      161 7814025216 sdcm1
 134      240 7814026583 sdif
 134      241 7814025216 sdif1
 131       64 7814026583 sdfy
 131       65 7814025216 sdfy1
  70      176 7814026583 sddd
  70      177 7814025216 sddd1
   8      256 7814026583 sdiw
   8      257 7814025216 sdiw1
 130      128 7814026583 sdfm
 130      129 7814025216 sdfm1
  71       96 7814026583 sddo
  71       97 7814025216 sddo1
  68      144 7814026583 sdbv
  68      145 7814025216 sdbv1
 135      240 7814026583 sdiv
 135      241 7814025216 sdiv1
 129      128 7814026583 sdew
 129      129 7814025216 sdew1
   8      352 7814026583 sdjc
   8      353 7814025216 sdjc1
  65      192 7814026583 sdac
  65      193 7814025216 sdac1
 134        0 7814026583 sdhq
 134        1 7814025216 sdhq1
   8      240 7814026583 sdp
   8      241 7814025216 sdp1
  70      112 7814026583 sdcz
  70      113 7814025216 sdcz1
 134      208 7814026583 sdid
 134      209 7814025216 sdid1
  67      208 7814026583 sdbj
  67      209 7814025216 sdbj1
 134       64 7814026583 sdhu
 134       65 7814025216 sdhu1
 132       64 7814026583 sdgo
 132       65 7814025216 sdgo1
 133       48 7814026583 sdhd
 133       49 7814025216 sdhd1
   8      336 7814026583 sdjb
   8      337 7814025216 sdjb1
  67       16 7814026583 sdax
  67       17 7814025216 sdax1
  67      160 7814026583 sdbg
  67      161 7814025216 sdbg1
 133       16 7814026583 sdhb
 133       17 7814025216 sdhb1
 129      192 7814026583 sdfa
 129      193 7814025216 sdfa1
  69      176 7814026583 sdcn
  69      177 7814025216 sdcn1
  65      144 7814026583 sdz
  65      145 7814025216 sdz1
 133      208 7814026583 sdhn
 133      209 7814025216 sdhn1
 129       80 7814026583 sdet
 129       81 7814025216 sdet1
 135       32 7814026583 sdii
 135       33 7814025216 sdii1
  70       16 7814026583 sdct
  70       17 7814025216 sdct1
  70       48 7814026583 sdcv
  70       49 7814025216 sdcv1
  69      128 7814026583 sdck
  69      129 7814025216 sdck1
 131       16 7814026583 sdfv
 131       17 7814025216 sdfv1
 131      176 7814026583 sdgf
 131      177 7814025216 sdgf1
  68       48 7814026583 sdbp
  68       49 7814025216 sdbp1
 130       32 7814026583 sdfg
 130       33 7814025216 sdfg1
 130       16 7814026583 sdff
 130       17 7814025216 sdff1
  69       96 7814026583 sdci
  69       97 7814025216 sdci1
 134      112 7814026583 sdhx
 134      113 7814025216 sdhx1
  68       64 7814026583 sdbq
  68       65 7814025216 sdbq1
  71      112 7814026583 sddp
  71      113 7814025216 sddp1
 130      112 7814026583 sdfl
 130      113 7814025216 sdfl1
  70      128 7814026583 sdda
  70      129 7814025216 sdda1
  67       64 7814026583 sdba
  67       65 7814025216 sdba1
 131      144 7814026583 sdgd
 131      145 7814025216 sdgd1
  69      224 7814026583 sdcq
  69      225 7814025216 sdcq1
  65      224 7814026583 sdae
  65      225 7814025216 sdae1
   8      160 7814026583 sdk
   8      161 7814025216 sdk1
  68       16 7814026583 sdbn
  68       17 7814025216 sdbn1
  66      160 7814026583 sdaq
  66      161 7814025216 sdaq1
 131      160 7814026583 sdge
 131      161 7814025216 sdge1
  70      160 7814026583 sddc
  70      161 7814025216 sddc1
  68      128 7814026583 sdbu
  68      129 7814025216 sdbu1
  67       48 7814026583 sdaz
  67       49 7814025216 sdaz1
 130      208 7814026583 sdfr
 130      209 7814025216 sdfr1
 131        0 7814026583 sdfu
 131        1 7814025216 sdfu1
 131      112 7814026583 sdgb
 131      113 7814025216 sdgb1
 132      176 7814026583 sdgv
 132      177 7814025216 sdgv1
 133       64 7814026583 sdhe
 133       65 7814025216 sdhe1
 133       32 7814026583 sdhc
 133       33 7814025216 sdhc1
 129      112 7814026583 sdev
 129      113 7814025216 sdev1
 135       96 7814026583 sdim
 135       97 7814025216 sdim1
  71        0 7814026583 sddi
  71        1 7814025216 sddi1
 132      112 7814026583 sdgr
 132      113 7814025216 sdgr1
  69      192 7814026583 sdco
  69      193 7814025216 sdco1
 132       32 7814026583 sdgm
 132       33 7814025216 sdgm1
 130       64 7814026583 sdfi
 130       65 7814025216 sdfi1
 128      208 7814026583 sdel
 128      209 7814025216 sdel1
 135       64 7814026583 sdik
 135       65 7814025216 sdik1
  66      240 7814026583 sdav
  66      241 7814025216 sdav1
 128      160 7814026583 sdei
 128      161 7814025216 sdei1
 135       48 7814026583 sdij
 135       49 7814025216 sdij1
 128       96 7814026583 sdee
 128       97 7814025216 sdee1
 133      112 7814026583 sdhh
 133      113 7814025216 sdhh1
 133      192 7814026583 sdhm
 133      193 7814025216 sdhm1
 134      128 7814026583 sdhy
 134      129 7814025216 sdhy1
  69       32 7814026583 sdce
  69       33 7814025216 sdce1
 131       96 7814026583 sdga
 131       97 7814025216 sdga1
 131       32 7814026583 sdfw
 131       33 7814025216 sdfw1
 130       96 7814026583 sdfk
 130       97 7814025216 sdfk1
 129       48 7814026583 sder
 129       49 7814025216 sder1
  69       16 7814026583 sdcd
  69       17 7814025216 sdcd1
 135      208 7814026583 sdit
 135      209 7814025216 sdit1
 132      144 7814026583 sdgt
 132      145 7814025216 sdgt1
 128        0 7814026583 sddy
 128        1 7814025216 sddy1
  68      224 7814026583 sdca
  68      225 7814025216 sdca1
 130        0 7814026583 sdfe
 130        1 7814025216 sdfe1
 130      240 7814026583 sdft
 130      241 7814025216 sdft1
 134       32 7814026583 sdhs
 134       33 7814025216 sdhs1
 131      192 7814026583 sdgg
 131      193 7814025216 sdgg1
 133      224 7814026583 sdho
 133      225 7814025216 sdho1
  70      208 7814026583 sddf
  70      209 7814025216 sddf1
 129      208 7814026583 sdfb
 129      209 7814025216 sdfb1
  67      112 7814026583 sdbd
  67      113 7814025216 sdbd1
 128      240 7814026583 sden
 128      241 7814025216 sden1
 128       80 7814026583 sded
 128       81 7814025216 sded1
 131       80 7814026583 sdfz
 131       81 7814025216 sdfz1
  68        0 7814026583 sdbm
  68        1 7814025216 sdbm1
 132      224 7814026583 sdgy
 132      225 7814025216 sdgy1
 129       32 7814026583 sdeq
 129       33 7814025216 sdeq1
  70        0 7814026583 sdcs
  70        1 7814025216 sdcs1
 134      176 7814026583 sdib
 134      177 7814025216 sdib1
 135      224 7814026583 sdiu
 135      225 7814025216 sdiu1
 130       48 7814026583 sdfh
 130       49 7814025216 sdfh1
 134       96 7814026583 sdhw
 134       97 7814025216 sdhw1
 131      224 7814026583 sdgi
 131      225 7814025216 sdgi1
  70      144 7814026583 sddb
  70      145 7814025216 sddb1
 133      144 7814026583 sdhj
 133      145 7814025216 sdhj1
```

Comment: can you give output of `cat /proc/partitions`?

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the 'onion' drive in fstab and ubuntu auto-mounts the drive when its connected. This same thing happens on a different system running ubuntu server except the drive is left unmounted.

Comment: is the device plugged with usb? can you also give `sudo lshw -c disk -c storage` and `lsusb -vvt` - it looks really strange, that one disk has many sdX devices.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there is roughly 256 pairs of whole-disk + partition devices in the `/proc/partitions` listing.

This might indicate the device ignores the Logical Unit Number (LUN) field of the SCSI command set used with USB storage devices, and just responds to requests on every possible LUN number. This is a known issue with certain storage devices.

As a work-around, you should find out the USB Vendor and Product IDs of the external hard drive. You can do this with the `lsusb` command. It should output one line for each plugged-in USB device, and the line should look similar to this:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
```

The hexadecimal numbers after the `ID` are exactly what you'll need. In the following example, I assume your device has `ID 1234:abcd`.

The next step is to unplug the storage device, and tell the USB storage subsystem that this device has a *single-lun* quirk.

The documentation for the known possible USB storage quirks [can be found in kernel source documentation (`<source package>/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt`)](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#5700).

For one-time testing, you could do it like this:

```
echo "1234:abcd:s" | sudo tee /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
```

Replace the `1234:abcd` part with the actual IDs of your device. This will cause no persistent changes: if this turns out to be not helpful, simply rebooting your system will get your system back to the original state.

Then plug the storage device in again. If it now presents just one device, and the storage device works correctly, the workaround is correct for your device.

To make the workaround persistent, you'll need to do one of two things, depending on whether your Linux distribution provides the USB storage subsystem as a loadable module or as built-in to the kernel. In the comments you mentioned Ubuntu, so I assume that's the distribution you're using.

Create a text file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory. You can name it anything you like, but the name needs to have a `.conf` suffix. For example, you could name it `/etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage-fix.conf`.

The contents of the file should be just a single line of text:

```
options usb-storage quirks=1234:abcd:s
```

Again, replace the `1234:abcd` part with the actual IDs of your USB storage device.

Note that you'll need to have root access to create or edit any files in `/etc/modprobe.d/`, so you might use a command like `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage-fix.conf` to create the file and edit its contents.

Once you've created the file, you'll need to rebuild your initramfs file, just in case your distribution loads the `usb_storage` kernel module early in the system start-up procedure. On Ubuntu, this is simple: just run `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Now, the workaround should get applied automatically whenever you plug in the USB device.

---

An alternative method for specifying the quirk for this USB storage device would be to use a kernel boot option. To do that, you would typically edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` line in `/etc/default/grub` to add the option `usb-storage.quirks=1234:abcd:s` to whatever is already within the double quotes.

After editing the file, you would need to rebuild the GRUB configuration file; in Ubuntu, that would be `sudo update-grub`; in other distributions, you might have to use `grub-mkconfig` directly, or use some other distribution-specific wrapper.

---

You might also want to email your findings to the usb-storage driver developers' mailing list (linux-usb@vger.kernel.org), so they will be able to make future kernel versions apply the workaround automatically whenever a device of this model is detected. The kernel already has a long list of USB storage devices with specific quirks, so this will be nothing particularly new or unusual.